# Read the contents of a project using an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to create a eclipse plugin which on click of a menu in the menu bar will scan all the project contents and give me idea about the use of a specified function if any such as isBoolean or isInteger etc..

I searched everywhere but not getting a clear idea about how to do it.I heard of IResource and Iproject API's but dint find any implementation of it.Could you please help me getting in the right direction .

I tried putting this in my action... 
but got "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchRequestor"

```
   SearchPattern pattern = SearchPattern.createPattern("isBool",  
            IJavaSearchConstants.METHOD, 
            IJavaSearchConstants.REFERENCES, 
            SearchPattern.R_EXACT_MATCH);

    IJavaSearchScope scope = SearchEngine.createWorkspaceScope();
    SearchRequestor requestor = new SearchRequestor() {

        @Override
        public void acceptSearchMatch(SearchMatch searchMatch) throws CoreException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println( searchMatch.getElement());

        }
    };

    SearchEngine searchEngine = new SearchEngine();
    try {
        searchEngine.search(
                pattern, 
                new SearchParticipant[]
                        {SearchEngine.getDefaultSearchParticipant()},
                        scope, requestor, null);
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Am I proceeding in the right direction? Or is there any changes need to be made..

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you mean a Java project.  You should have a look at the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine` API.

You need to do something like this:

```
SearchPattern pattern = SearchPattern.createPattern("isBoolean",  IJavaSearchConstants.METHOD, IJavaSearchConstants.REFERENCES, SearchPattern.EXACT_MATCH);
new SearchEngine().search(
    SearchEngine.createJavaSearchScope(patter, 
    new SearchParticipant[] { SearchEngine.getDefaultSearchParticipant() },
    new IJavaElement[] { iJavaProject }),
    requestor,
    new NullProgressMonitor());
```

Where `requestor` is the thing that asynchronously receives (and processes) your match results.

Comment: @eisenberg I am trying for android apk projects also

Comment: do i need to add some jars as my SearchEngine and iJavaProject are not getting identified by eclipse..

Comment: Yes. You need org.eclipse.jdt.core and maybe some other ones.

Comment: I am trying for the first time actually ..so dont know much about the API..could you help me with the jars which i need to import..

Comment: Please see my post..I have made some changes in that as u have said

Comment: SearchRequestor is in the org.eclipse.jdt.core bundle.  You must add this bundle to your manifest.  If you are getting a ClassNotFoundException, then you have not added it properly.

Comment: Now I am able to compile it but I am not getting any output or errors..the *acceptSearchMatch(SearchMatch searchMatch)* method is not getting run during the run time..could you help me with this..

Comment: I am just telling you what I exactly want..when I click on a sample menu in the menu bar I should get a report which would show me that what specific functions I have used and how many times.Now I have implemented your code and when I run it as an eclipse application , I create a new project in that and create some xml/txt files and write the function names in that.When I click on the sample menu I am not getting any info about whether the function are present or not etc..

Comment: This code will only work in *.java files.  If you want to search in non java files, then you will have to implement something custom (ie- find the files and walk through the contents yourself.